# Stack [aws-sam-cli-managed-default] already exists and cannot be created again with the changeSet [InitialCreation]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-sam

## Question

I encountered the following error when deploying my aws SAM application using aws cli tool. Does anyone know why it occurs and how to fix it?

```
Error: Failed to create managed resources: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Stack [aws-sam-cli-managed-default] already exists and cannot be created again with the changeSet [InitialCreation].
```

## Detail

I have not used `aws-sam-cli-managed-default` as CloudFormation stack name/SAM application name/ S3_prefix/ S3_bucket name.

## my samconfig.toml file

```
version = 0.1
[default]
[default.deploy]
[default.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "iot"
s3_bucket = "iot"
s3_prefix = "iot"
region = "us-east-2"
profile = "default"
confirm_changeset = true
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
```

Comment: Any results with `aws cloudformation list-stacks --region us-east-2`?

Answer (score 1):

I met same problem : i wasn't passing the stack name correctly. So it creates a default one **"aws-sam-cli-managed-default"** ... and this one was already existing as the message said.

So two options:

- You delete the previous stack with the same name if you don't want to use a specific name for your stack
- You check that your stack name is correctly passed

You can use a flag with the sam command : **"--stack-name YOUR_STACK_NAME"**

Or use the samconfig.toml file and check that the file is located at the root of your project, where you run your "sam deploy" command.

Answer (score 0):

I face Same issue, when i trying to deploy my code using aws codebuild services,
this error occure because of samconfig.toml the file's permissions are set in such a way that only the root user or users with root privileges, when you try just `sam deploy` it's not able to read samconfig.toml, therefore you need to execute your command with `sudo` keyword and then it's reffering the samconfig.toml file.

this is my buildSpec.yml script for aws CodeBuild deployment with sam framework.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 18
    commands:
      - echo 'setup AWS credentials..'
      - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - aws configure set default_region $AWS_REGION
      - aws configure set output json
      - echo 'installing npm packages...'
      - npm ci
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo 'Building Sam folder...'
      - sam build
  build:
    commands:
      - echo 'Building Nest js...'
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo 'Deploying...'
      - sudo sam deploy --parameter-overrides AWSSecretAccessKey=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWSAccessKeyId=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWSRegion=$AWS_REGION --no-confirm-changeset --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
artifacts:
  files:
    - template.yml
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
```